# Rather x <= 1 or x < 2?

Tags: language-agnostic, operators

Say we have `x` which is an integer.

is there any reason to prefer `x <= 1` or `x < 2`? I mean if one is maybe faster or more readable.

This question is language independant, meaning if the answer is different for two different languages, please let me know.

Comment: It depends on the context where you use this (what the meaning of `x` is etc.), there is no good answer to this question for the general case. Use whatever is more clear and meaningful for the specific context.

Comment: While on the surface this might seem to be language-agnostic, it really depends on the language, its implementation and what hardware instructions the compiler or interpreter might translate the operators to. Also some languages have operator overloading, where one could define special user-functions for operators which might make the two operators *very* different.

Comment: Every language running on Intel architecture will eventually translate these  to JLE or JL instructions, which are both equally time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I loop over a zero-based collection, I use `i < col.Length`, as it is more readable than `i <= col.Length - 1`. If I am iterating from 1 to x, I use `for (int i = 1; i <= x ...)`, as it is more readable than `< x + 1`. Both of theese instructions have the same time requirement (at least on x86 architecture), so yes, it is only about readability.

Comment: Very interesting, +1. But I cannot mark this as the solution because I a comparing `x` to an integer, not a variable. If I do compare `x` to a variable, than it would indeed depend on the usage and avoiding to put `x <= y - 1` or `x < y + 1`

Comment: @GiorgioCavicchioli What are you comparing for? If it is not a loop, then you should know better what operator to use (purchase can be made if account balance is greater or equal than the cost, penalty should be applied if the car's speed was strictly greater than the speed limit). If you just looping, then it is about readability, as stated in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it depends on the requirements of your software, was it specified that `x` needs to be one or less or was it specified that `x` needs to be less than two?

If you ever changed `x` to be of a number type that allows decimal points, which way would work best then? This happens more often than you think and can introduce some interesting bugs.

Comment: Interesting reflexion, but it is clearly stated that `x` will be entire, so as far as usage goes, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no evidence what types the literals 1 and 2 have. In most languages they will be the same, but in theory they could be different and then the results of two comparisons could be different as well. Also, integers are not infinite in most languages, so the behavior could be different on boundaries.

In plain C, if the comparisons are `x <= -0x80000000` and `x < -0x7fffffff` (note that `-0x80000000 < -0x7fffffff`) and `x` has type `int`, the results depend on the value of x:

```
-0x80000000                    : 1 1
-0x7fffffff .. -1              : 0 0
                0 .. 0x7fffffff: 1 0
```

In other words, for all non-negative `x`, the results will be different.

Similarly, with comparisons `x <=  0x7fffffff` and `x < 0x80000000` (the relation between constants `0x7fffffff < 0x80000000` still holds), we get:

```
-0x80000000 .. -1              : 1 0
                0 .. 0x7fffffff: 1 1
```

Now the results are different for all negative values of `x`.

Clearly, there are some typing rules and type conversions involved (they are described in the C language standard), but the point is that the two comparisons are not replaceable on boundary cases.